# Open window to add chrome extension when the page loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a javascript that opens the option of adding a chrome extension when the page is loading.
I have this script below.
What am I doing wrong, it does not work?

```
   <script>
    function onPageLoad(event)
    {
        javascript:chrome.webstore.install();
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onPageLoad, true);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed and will throw an exception, `chrome.webstore.install()` can only be called after a user gesture, like a click. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#triggering) is the documentation for this.